Roundcube Reaction Plugin or Webmail client alternative
I'm looking for a Roundcube reaction plugin to allow the user to react with “celebrate” “like” or other reactions just like the one already available in Outlook 365. If it is not possible, could you recommend an alternative client that would have this feature?
